# switching between open application windows

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I just updated my Ubuntu version to 14.04 LTS and the key combination 'Alt + Tab' does not work anymore to switch between open windows. I tried to redefine them by means of the keyboard shortcuts but was not successful as I tried a few combinations (including Alt+Tab) but no one of them works. Any new trick? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you might have installed a third-party program that interrupts the shortcut. If you installed anything weird, try uninstalling it.

You might want to check out your keys and see if they are working properly physically. It might not be Ubuntu's fault.

If all else fails, you could always use Xubuntu 14.04 (or Xfce on Ubuntu) instead. Alt+tab works fine for me there. I'm pretty sure it worked fine on regular Ubuntu 14.04, too, for me, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I finally found a post that led me to this CompizConfig Settings manager and there I could find, under window management, that the box for the Application switcher was not checked. Somehow the update to Ubuntu 14 changed that setting. By checking that box, it started working! Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad you found out the problem. Thanks for reporting back here. Ah, so you updated Ubuntu without completely reinstalling it? I could see that causing weird issues. I always just have a separate partition for my home directory and when a new Ubuntu version comes out, instead of upgrading, to avoid issues I install it completely fresh on the root partition (or if I'm dual-booting, over whichever root partition I want to). I've never upgraded without issues before (although a lot of people seem to think it's fine). I think reinstalling is easier for my system.